# Hexo Github Pages Static Site doesn't work online but works locally

Tags: github-pages, hexo

### Environment Info

Node version(`node -v`)

`v5.7.0`

Your site `_config.yml`

## Hexo Configuration

`url: http://akshaykadam.me/
root: /test/
theme: cactus-dark`

Site located [here](http://akshaykadam.me/test/). Checkout the console

The problem is it doesn't load `/vendor/` folder at all on Github Pages.
I've set it up right & gh-pages branch contains all locations perfectly.
I have tried too much to debug it, as it works locally & doesn't work on gh-pages

[Here is my compiled code](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/test)

## index.html

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/vendor/meslo-LG/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/vendor/justified-gallery/justifiedGallery.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/css/style.css">
<script src="/test/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Still it logs Resource Not Found

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question !!

Actually Github excludes `vendor/` & `node_modules/` folder by itself

So I changed the name of `vendor/` to `lib/` & its working